# How can I pin an image to the background of my Tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have made a simple widget with a background that auto-resizes to the shape of the  window. So far the image I have placed doesn't properly stick to the desired point of the background. Can anyone explain how I can properly fix the image to the moving background rather than the window, any help is appreciated.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import webbrowser
     class App(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master, Buttons=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, master, Buttons)
            self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
            self.original = Image.open(r"C:\specific\image.gif")
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)
            self.display = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
            self.display.create_image(500, 500, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")
            self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
            self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
            self.Buttons()
            self.Vehicles()

        def resize(self, event):
            size = (event.width, event.height)
            resized = self.original.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            self.display.delete("IMG")
            self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")

        def Buttons(self):
            self.VButton = tk.Button(master=self, text = "not relevant", font=('Arial, 8')) #, command = forward).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
            self.VButton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N, columnspan=2)

            def qlink():
                webbrowser.open_new(r"http://172.16.0.926/big/")

            self.QButton = tk.Button(master=self, text = "not relevant", font=('Arial, 8'), command = qlink) 
            self.QButton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NW, pady=30, columnspan=2)

            def Link():
                webbrowser.open_new(r"\\con\UserData\hello\Project\Vserver\file.html")

            self.GraphButton = tk.Button(master=self, font=('Arial, 8'), text = "not needed", command = Link) 
            self.GraphButton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NW, pady=60, columnspan=2)

            self.HelpButton = tk.Button(master=self, font=('Arial, 8'), text = "also not relevant") #, command = forward).pack(side = tk.LEFT)
            self.HelpButton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N, pady=90, columnspan=2)


        def Vehicles(self):
            width = 50
            height = 25
            image = Image.open(r"C:\specific\newimage.png")
            image =image.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            label = Label(image=photo)
            label.image = photo
            label.place(x=500, y=600)



    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is giving errors. Can you include the imports as well?

Comment: @amanb I've made the changes, I chopped the code up to only include relevant parts - apologies

Comment: Still getting an error: `AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'Buttons'`.

Comment: @amanb i removed the buttons as they're not relevant to the issue...ill add them back in

Comment: I got it working without the Buttons, but not sure what you mean by moving background. I only see an image in the window which resizes itself with the window.

Comment: @amanb thats what I mean, the image will resize according to window size, thats all its meant to be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186699/discussion-between-amanb-and-ecsync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion, your requirement is to position the image in the `Vehicles()` function relative to the parent Window with the background image. In your code, you have used absolute positioning for the `label` in the `Vehicles()` function:

```
def Vehicles(self):
        #---code----           
        label.place(x=500, y=600)
```

What you need is relative positioning of the label which is done like below. I've anchored the image to the center of the screen as an example. You can change this location as per your requirement by changing the value of the `anchor` argument.

```
def Vehicles(self):
        #---code----           
        label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

The image should now change co-ordinates based on the size of the parent window. Make sure you replace the absolute position statement with the relative position statement as you cannot have both.